# EntityFramework7 - Conventions, Properties and Configurations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Trying to update to EntityFramework7, but having trouble finding these methods.  In EF6, we could do things like this

Conventions

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Properties

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
            .Configure(c => c
                .HasColumnType("datetime2")
                .HasPrecision(0));
```

Configurations

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ModuleConfig());
```

I have read 1 stackoverflow post, that says Configurations are no longer possible, so you have to write all this in the OnModalCreating method, which seems stupid, as the method will be massive, but maybe this was a older version?

I am using beta7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that beta7 is not yet feature complete, and that even RC1 will not have feature parity with EF6.

Custom conventions are on the [backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/214).

For properties you could something like the following;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
{
    foreach (var type in builder.Model.EntityTypes.Where(type => type.HasClrType))
    {
        foreach (var property in type.Properties)
        {
            if (property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                builder.Entity(type.ClrType)
                    .Property(property.ClrType, property.Name)
                    .HasSqlServerColumnType("datetime2(0)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .GetClrTypes doesnt exist? And is builder supposed to be modelBuilder?

Comment: hah, looks like I'd made a method for when I did a similar thing.  Updated.

Comment: Do you know anything about Configurations?  Or do i have to have a BIG OnModelCreating method and have it all there?

Comment: Not sure, never used them in EF6.

Comment: U just have a large OnModelCreating method then i guess?

Comment: That's the only examples I've seen so far yeah